# retain hyperlink XML-XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, hyperlink, xslt-1.0

I have sample XML as below.

```
<Text>
  <links>Go for a test-drive, visit us online at http://abc.com/link</links> 
</Text>
```

I want to perform XSL transformation, where I have to check whether the string contains a hyperlink and retain the link `http://abc.com/link` as a hyperlink.

Is there any function that I could use for this or any examples available??

Thanks

Comment: If XSLT v2.0 can be used, you can use xsl:analyze-string instruction. If you need to stick to XSLTv1.0 try to find some regular expression extension funtions for your XSLT processor.

Comment: Well known set of extension functions supported by many processors can be found at exslt.org . Regular expression function with example similar to your needs can be found here http://www.exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/index.html